# How to incorporate prior knowledge in GPML?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, gaussian-process

I am using the [MATLAB code](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/index.html) for Rasmussen & Williams' book *Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning*.

How can one incorporate prior knowledge in Gaussian process regression? Say, that the variance in one dimension of a two dimensional vector is greater. Is it only by considering the parameters of a normal distribution, or can it be more detailed?

Comment: The prior is Gaussian. Do you have the actual book? If not, you can read the co-author's [summary](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hutter/earg/papers05/rasmussen_gps_in_ml.pdf). Hanna Wallach also has an [introductory presentation](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~wallach/talks/gp_intro.pdf)

Comment: Then it is not really a prior knowledge ! If I already know that the influence of variable A is more than variable B, then how should I consider it ?!

Comment: so basically it is not possible ?!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Gelman et.al. Bayesian Data Analysis (Third Edition), chapter 21 which has a Bayesian treatment of Gaussian processes. It also has good applied examples.